# ESLINT An error occurred while generating your JavaScript config file. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.3.0

Error: An error occurred while generating your JavaScript config file. A config file was still generated, but the config file itself may not follow your linting rules.
Error: BaseConfig » eslint-config-airbnb-base » D:\dev_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb-base\rules\imports.js:
Configuration for rule "import/no-cycle" is invalid:
Value null should be integer.

```
at validateRuleOptions (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\shared\config-validator.js:132:19)
at D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\shared\config-validator.js:187:9
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validateRules (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\shared\config-validator.js:184:30)
at validateConfigArray (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\shared\config-validator.js:312:9)
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:464:13)
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:275:21)
at CLIEngine.executeOnText (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:869:47)
at writeJSConfigFile (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\init\config-file.js:92:31)
at Object.write (D:\dev\_ongoing\fullstack-twitter-clone\server\node_modules\eslint\lib\init\config-file.js:120:13)
```

Comment: maybe this is because the airbnb config does not support your eslint version, see [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/2245).

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: ESLint have pushed the version 7.3.1 that should fix your problem.
[ESLint merged patch](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/13435)

Have in mind that currently ESLint v7.3.0 won't work with eslint-airbnb-config. There's a bug being discussed in both the ESLint and Airbnb config repos, and for the moment there are no other fix rather than downgrading to ESLint v7.2.0.
[airbnb-eslint-config issue](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/2245) caused by [ESLint bug](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13427)

I suggest downgrading to ESLint v7.2.0 like so:

```
npm uninstall eslint
npm install eslint@7.2.0
```

And then you can use the ESLint included assistant to create a new config:

```
eslint --init
```